# Memory usage of `numpy.random`

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, memory, random

Consider the following script:

```
import numpy as np
import tracemalloc

def zero_mem():
    a = np.zeros((100, 100))

def nonzero_mem():
    b = np.random.randn(100, 100)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    tracemalloc.start()
    zero_mem()
    print(tracemalloc.get_traced_memory())
    tracemalloc.stop()

    tracemalloc.start()
    nonzero_mem()
    print(tracemalloc.get_traced_memory())
    tracemalloc.stop()
```

The output running `numpy 1.22.2` on `python 3.8.10` is

```
(0, 80096)
(72, 80168)
```

The question is: why isn't the second row `(0, 80168)`? In other words: why is there memory still in use after `nonzero_mem()`, unlike when calling `zero_mem()`?

Comment: Does this happen on every call of `np.random.randn`, or just the first call in the script?

Comment: Can you please edit to match the question to the code? The code has no `f()` or `g()`.

Comment: Adding a second call to `nonzero_mem()` right after the first one, the second row is still `(0, 80168)`. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Right; so the first call does some deferred initialisation

Comment: Two comments above, I meant  " still `(72, 80168)` "

Comment: Importing tracemalloc before numpy may change the situation. Could you try that?

Comment: @ken inverting the imports gave the "expected" result of `(0, 80096)` for both cases. I guess my original question can be rephrased as: why does order matter?